# Migration fails when extending Django User Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-users

I'm trying to extend django User model by inheriting AbstractBaseUser so i can be able to manipulate the authentication process of the project.

Here is what my model looks like.

```
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    ... create_user
    ... create_superuser


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

And here is my settings `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'rest_framework',
    'compressor',
    'authentication'
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.Account'
```

The problem here i notice the migration process that django is bypassing the `auth.0001_initial` and it jumped directly creating the `admin.0001_initial` making my migrations to fail with

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, u'Cannot add foreign key constraint')`

How can i fixed this please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue, by this simple steps:

1. run `python manage.py makemigrations authentication` - because when using `AUTH_USER_MODEL` it will replace the migration of `auth_user` table of `django.contrib.auth` altering the migration process. Thus if we fail to provide migration file for `authentication` app migration will no doubt fails.
2. run `python manage.py migrate`.

Binggo!

Comment: I get this: No installed app with label 'authentication'

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan 'authentication' is the name of his app. you should use the name of your app instead. python manage.py migrate your_app_name